# How does a PHP script send an JSON Ajax response to Dojo's xhrGet?

Tags: php, ajax, json, dojo

I just started using dojo and I'm onto using Ajax in dojo via xhrGet.

I understand that whatever you "echo" in PHP is what is returned as the Ajax result, however how does this work with JSON?

Does the PHP script echo javascript code that is then directly accessed from the function called by xhrGet?

I'm trying to have a PHP script retrieve data from the database, populate three arrays, and make them available in my javascript code, all with xhrGet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the header with PHP before you echo:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo '{"myJsonKey":"myJsonVal"}';
```

For your specific case, you'd do something like this:

```
<?php
    $my_records_array = fetch_records($some_criteria);
    $my_records_json  = json_encode($my_records_array);

    header('Content-type: application/json'); 
    echo $my_records_json;
```

Comment: Ah I see. So if I have three statements all encoding three different arrays using json_encode, I would be able to access those via my load call in the xhrGet using response.whateverArray? Also, if I'm passing something using "content" of xhrGet, do I use the $_GET array or the $_REQUEST array? I've seen both used. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and always use `$_GET` vs `$_REQUEST` as `$_REQUEST` is a combination of `$_GET` and `$_POST` among others.

Answer (score 0):

Most JavaScript libraries wrap a callback around the AJAX request. I'm not sure about Dojo, but jQuery adds a callback param to the URL when it's sent.

Then, when the server responds it triggers that callback which calls *your* callback to handle the result.

As for the actual server side stuff, the server usually just prints the JSON encoded string and passes along an extra header letting the browser know what type of content it is.

```
<?php
$rows = $db->fetch($sql);

header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```